# Multithread C++ program to speed up a summatory loop

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, algorithm

I have a loop that iterates from 1 to N and takes a modular sum over time. However N is very large and so I am wondering if there is a way to modify it by taking advantage of multithread.

To give sample program

```
for (long long i = 1; i < N; ++i)
   total = (total + f(i)) % modulus;
```

f(i) in my case isn't an actual function, but a long expression that would take up room here. Putting it there to illustrate purpose.

Comment: If you really wan to speed it up try using cuda also can I ask what the purpose of this loop is

Comment: A really simple optimization - save the % modulus for the end.  Arithmetically, there's no reason to do it inside the loop, unless you're doing it to help prevent overflow.  (Thanks to @Xaqq for catching my previous too-broad generalization.)

Comment: @ScottMermelstein Maybe it would overflow without it. But yeah, if you can save it for end, do it.

Comment: Would overflow, modulus required.

Comment: yeah, give each thread its own total, have them each sum up unique ranges, then when they're all finished and joined, add the totals.

Comment: @JoeRunde Correct but I do not know how to do that, hence the question

Comment: I just told you how, so go choose a threading api, boost's is pretty easy, read the documentation, try to implement it, and come back when you need help with that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, try this:

```
double total=0;
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:total)
for (long long i = 1; i < N; ++i)
  total = (total + f(i)) % modulus;
```

Compile with:

```
g++ -fopenmp your_program.c
```

It's that simple! No headers are required. The `#pragma` line automatically spins up a couple of threads, divides the iterations of the loop evenly, and then recombines everything after the loop. Note though, that you must know the number of iterations beforehand.

This code uses [OpenMP](http://openmp.org/wp/), which provides easy-to-use parallelism that's quite suitable to your case. OpenMP is even built-in to the GCC and [MSVC compilers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw509c3b.aspx).

[This page](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/getting-started-with-openmp) shows some of the other reduction operations that are possible.

If you need nested for loops, you can just write

```
double total=0;
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:total)
for (long long i = 1; i < N; ++i)
for (long long j = 1; j < N; ++j)
  total = (total + f(i)*j) % modulus;
```

And the outer loop will be parallelised, with each thread running its own copy of the inner loop.

But you could also use the [collapse](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/openmp-loop-collapse-directive) directive:

```
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:total) collapse(2)
```

and then the iterations of *both* loops will be automagically divied up.

If each thread needs its own copy of a variable defined prior to the loop, use the `private` command:

```
double total=0, cheese=4;
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:total) private(cheese)
for (long long i = 1; i < N; ++i)
  total = (total + f(i)) % modulus;
```

Note that you don't need to use `private(total)` because this is implied by `reduction`.

Comment: How does this work? What if the sum is over a double loop, or if more than one variable is involved other than total?

Comment: If the sum is over a double loop, the iterations of the outer loops will be divided between the threads and each thread will run its own copies of the inner loop.

Comment: You can have as many `reduction` clauses as you would like, though you should be make careful note of the `private` and `shared` commands, which isolate variables to particular threads.

Comment: So let's say I had a triple loop, i=1 to A, j=1 to B, k=1 to C. Would using the same pragma statement you have listed split up the loop by the i=1 to A loop?

Comment: @MrP, see my modified answer. In short, you can parallelise the outer loop alone (i=1 to A) or you can parallelise over all the iterations (with certain restrictions).

Comment: Thank you very much; I'll have to play around with this

Comment: Good luck, @MrP - I believe you'll find this method of parallelism easy to use, understand, and maintain.

Comment: Note you'll need one more modulus after this loop `total %= modulus`, the reduction clause will only add the total of each thread for you which in general will not be between `0` and `modulus-1`

Comment: When I am trying this out it isn't actually speeding anything up unfortunately, same timings as before

Comment: @MrP, which compiler are you using? If you are using GCC, compile with `-fopenmp -Wall` as compiler flags. The first includes OpenMP, the second spits out all kinds of warnings, which may allow you to diagnose the issue.

Comment: @Richard I tried including that flag and I get "g++: error: libgomp.spec: No such file or directory"

Comment: @MrP, which version of g++ are you using? And have you Googled this particular error?

Comment: @Richard g++ (GCC) 4.7.2. And yes but nothing seemed to help much. I don't see the file on my HDD anywhere. A lot of results were very "Linuxy" and I use Windows.

Comment: @MrP, are you compiling this on Windows with g++? I'd think that the error would be best spun out into a separate question - that way it'll be more than just me helping you solve it.

Comment: @Richard http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17118265/g-error-libgomp-spec-no-such-file-or-directory

Answer (score 2):

As presumably the f(i) are independent but take the same time roughly to run, you could create yourself 4 threads, and get each to sum up 1/4 of the total, then return the sum as a value, and join each one. This isn't a very flexible method, especially if the times the f(i) times can be random.

You might also want to consider a thread pool, and make each thread calculate f(i) then get the next i to sum.

Comment: This is not a valid answer as it is a rephrasing of what I am asking for

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Threading Building Blocks](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/)

```
tbb::parallel_for(1, N, [=](long long i) {
  total = (total + f(i)) % modulus;
});
```

Or whitout overflow checks:

```
tbb::parallel_for(1, N, [=](long long i) {
  total = (total + f(i));
});
total %= modulus;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try openMP's parallel for with the reduction clause for your `total` http://bisqwit.iki.fi/story/howto/openmp/#ReductionClause

Answer (score 0):

If `f(long long int)` is a function that solely relies on its input and no global state and the abelian properties of addition hold, you can gain a significant advantage like this:

```
for(long long int i = 0, j = 1; i < N; i += 2, j += 2)
{
    total1 = (total1 + f(i)) % modulus;
    total2 = (total2 + f(j)) % modulus;
}

total = (total1 + total2) % modulus;
```

Breaking this out like that *should* help by allowing the compiler to improve code generation and the CPU to use more resources (the two operations can be handled in parallel) and pump more data out and reduce stalls. [I am assuming an x86 architecture here]

Of course, without knowing what `f` really looks like, it's hard to be sure if this is possible or if it will really help or make a measurable difference.

There may be other similar tricks that you can exploit special knowledge of your input and your platform - for example, SSE instructions could allow you to do even more. Platform-specific functionality might also be useful. For example, a modulo operation may not be required at all and your compiler may provide a special intrinsic function to perform addition modulo N.

I must ask, have you profiled your code and found this to be a hotspot?

Comment: I don't know how to profile code properly, but it is a hotspot

Comment: I think you mean `i+=2, j+=2`. Also, notice that OP loop starts at `1`, though it's a minor point (nitpick some would say)